# How to connect to remote machine via WinRM in Python (pywinrm) using domain account?

Tags: python, winrm

I would like to write a script in Python using pywinrm library to be able to connect to remote machine via WinRM.

```
import winrm

s = winrm.Session('MACHINEHOST', auth=('username@domain', 'password'))
r = s.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all'])

print r.status_code
print r.std_out
```

Script is working fine when I use local user. When I use domain user, I receive the following exception:

```
winrm.exceptions.UnauthorizedError: 401 Unauthorized.
```

As to the WinRM configuration on remote machine:

```
/Client/Auth/Basic = True
/Client/TrustedHosts = *
/Service/Auth/Basic = True
/Service/AllowUnencrypted = True
```

Could you advise how to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: It is advised to use Kerberos for remote hosts on a domain.

Answer (score 7):

### Pywinrm to connect using domain user account:

#### In Remote Windows Machine

1. Make sure in the target windows machine the network connection type is "private", if it is "public" winrm would not get configured.
2. Open command prompt and type:

   ```
   winrm qc
   winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
   ```
3. Open Powershell and type:

   ```
   enable-psremoting
   set-item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts * # ('*' is for all hosts, you may specify the host you want)
   ```

#### In your Python Code

4. In your python script:

   ```
   import winrm

   host = 'YourWindowsHost'
   domain = 'YourDomain'
   user = 'YourDomainUser'
   password = 'YourPassword'

   session = winrm.Session(host, auth=('{}@{}'.format(user,domain), password), transport='ntlm')

   result = session.run_cmd('ipconfig', ['/all']) # To run command in cmd

   result = session.run_ps('Get-Acl') # To run Powershell block
   ```

Answer (score 5):

As Steve Barnes said, you user should kerberos to connect using your domain account.

You will first need a kerberos ticket set up for your account.  Windows will give this to you automatically, but under linux you will need to kinit.  Use klist to see your current and default tickets.

```
session = winrm.Session(server, auth=('user@DOMAIN', 'doesNotMatterBecauseYouAreUsingAKerbTicket'), transport='kerberos')
```

I believe your domain account needs to have admin permissions on the windows host.

Also note that in version 0.0.3 of pywinrm you can specify the auth param as:

```
auth=(None, None)
```

This is because pywinrm is using your default kerberos ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Use this powershell script to enable winrm and configure winrm to all your windows nodes

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1

```
[CmdletBinding()]

Param (
    [string]$SubjectName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
    [int]$CertValidityDays = 1095,
    [switch]$SkipNetworkProfileCheck,
    $CreateSelfSignedCert = $true,
    [switch]$ForceNewSSLCert,
    [switch]$GlobalHttpFirewallAccess,
    [switch]$DisableBasicAuth = $false,
    [switch]$EnableCredSSP
)

Function Write-Log
{
    $Message = $args[0]
    Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $EventSource -EntryType Information -EventId 1 -Message $Message
}

Function Write-VerboseLog
{
    $Message = $args[0]
    Write-Verbose $Message
    Write-Log $Message
}

Function Write-HostLog
{
    $Message = $args[0]
    Write-Output $Message
    Write-Log $Message
}

Function New-LegacySelfSignedCert
{
    Param (
        [string]$SubjectName,
        [int]$ValidDays = 1095
    )

    $name = New-Object -COM "X509Enrollment.CX500DistinguishedName.1"
    $name.Encode("CN=$SubjectName", 0)

    $key = New-Object -COM "X509Enrollment.CX509PrivateKey.1"
    $key.ProviderName = "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider"
    $key.KeySpec = 1
    $key.Length = 4096
    $key.SecurityDescriptor = "D:PAI(A;;0xd01f01ff;;;SY)(A;;0xd01f01ff;;;BA)(A;;0x80120089;;;NS)"
    $key.MachineContext = 1
    $key.Create()

    $serverauthoid = New-Object -COM "X509Enrollment.CObjectId.1"
    $serverauthoid.InitializeFromValue("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1")
    $ekuoids = New-Object -COM "X509Enrollment.CObjectIds.1"
    $ekuoids.Add($serverauthoid)
    $ekuext = New-Object -COM "X509Enrollment.CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage.1"
    $ekuext.InitializeEncode($ekuoids)

    $cert = New-Object -COM "X509Enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestCertificate.1"
    $cert.InitializeFromPrivateKey(2, $key, "")
    $cert.Subject = $name
    $cert.Issuer = $cert.Subject
    $cert.NotBefore = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
    $cert.NotAfter = $cert.NotBefore.AddDays($ValidDays)
    $cert.X509Extensions.Add($ekuext)
    $cert.Encode()

    $enrollment = New-Object -COM "X509Enrollment.CX509Enrollment.1"
    $enrollment.InitializeFromRequest($cert)
    $certdata = $enrollment.CreateRequest(0)
    $enrollment.InstallResponse(2, $certdata, 0, "")

    # extract/return the thumbprint from the generated cert
    $parsed_cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
    $parsed_cert.Import([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($certdata))

    return $parsed_cert.Thumbprint
}

Function Enable-GlobalHttpFirewallAccess
{
    Write-Verbose "Forcing global HTTP firewall access"
    # this is a fairly naive implementation; could be more sophisticated about rule matching/collapsing
    $fw = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.FWPolicy2

    # try to find/enable the default rule first
    $add_rule = $false
    $matching_rules = $fw.Rules | ? { $_.Name -eq "Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)" }
    $rule = $null
    If ($matching_rules) {
        If ($matching_rules -isnot [Array]) {
            Write-Verbose "Editing existing single HTTP firewall rule"
            $rule = $matching_rules
        }
        Else {
            # try to find one with the All or Public profile first
            Write-Verbose "Found multiple existing HTTP firewall rules..."
            $rule = $matching_rules | % { $_.Profiles -band 4 }[0]

            If (-not $rule -or $rule -is [Array]) {
                Write-Verbose "Editing an arbitrary single HTTP firewall rule (multiple existed)"
                # oh well, just pick the first one
                $rule = $matching_rules[0]
            }
        }
    }

    If (-not $rule) {
        Write-Verbose "Creating a new HTTP firewall rule"
        $rule = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.FWRule
        $rule.Name = "Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)"
        $rule.Description = "Inbound rule for Windows Remote Management via WS-Management. [TCP 5985]"
        $add_rule = $true
    }

    $rule.Profiles = 0x7FFFFFFF
    $rule.Protocol = 6
    $rule.LocalPorts = 5985
    $rule.RemotePorts = "*"
    $rule.LocalAddresses = "*"
    $rule.RemoteAddresses = "*"
    $rule.Enabled = $true
    $rule.Direction = 1
    $rule.Action = 1
    $rule.Grouping = "Windows Remote Management"

    If ($add_rule) {
        $fw.Rules.Add($rule)
    }

    Write-Verbose "HTTP firewall rule $($rule.Name) updated"
}

# Setup error handling.
Trap
{
    $_
    Exit 1
}
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# Get the ID and security principal of the current user account
$myWindowsID=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$myWindowsPrincipal=new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($myWindowsID)

# Get the security principal for the Administrator role
$adminRole=[System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator

# Check to see if we are currently running "as Administrator"
if (-Not $myWindowsPrincipal.IsInRole($adminRole))
{
    Write-Output "ERROR: You need elevated Administrator privileges in order to run this script."
    Write-Output "       Start Windows PowerShell by using the Run as Administrator option."
    Exit 2
}

$EventSource = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
If (-Not $EventSource)
{
    $EventSource = "Powershell CLI"
}

If ([System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::Exists('Application') -eq $False -or [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::SourceExists($EventSource) -eq $False)
{
    New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source $EventSource
}

# Detect PowerShell version.
If ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 3)
{
    Write-Log "PowerShell version 3 or higher is required."
    Throw "PowerShell version 3 or higher is required."
}

# Find and start the WinRM service.
Write-Verbose "Verifying WinRM service."
If (!(Get-Service "WinRM"))
{
    Write-Log "Unable to find the WinRM service."
    Throw "Unable to find the WinRM service."
}
ElseIf ((Get-Service "WinRM").Status -ne "Running")
{
    Write-Verbose "Setting WinRM service to start automatically on boot."
    Set-Service -Name "WinRM" -StartupType Automatic
    Write-Log "Set WinRM service to start automatically on boot."
    Write-Verbose "Starting WinRM service."
    Start-Service -Name "WinRM" -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Log "Started WinRM service."

}

# WinRM should be running; check that we have a PS session config.
If (!(Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Verbose:$false) -or (!(Get-ChildItem WSMan:\localhost\Listener)))
{
  If ($SkipNetworkProfileCheck) {
    Write-Verbose "Enabling PS Remoting without checking Network profile."
    Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Log "Enabled PS Remoting without checking Network profile."
  }
  Else {
    Write-Verbose "Enabling PS Remoting."
    Enable-PSRemoting -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Log "Enabled PS Remoting."
  }
}
Else
{
    Write-Verbose "PS Remoting is already enabled."
}

# Make sure there is a SSL listener.
$listeners = Get-ChildItem WSMan:\localhost\Listener
If (!($listeners | Where {$_.Keys -like "TRANSPORT=HTTPS"}))
{
    # We cannot use New-SelfSignedCertificate on 2012R2 and earlier
    $thumbprint = New-LegacySelfSignedCert -SubjectName $SubjectName -ValidDays $CertValidityDays
    Write-HostLog "Self-signed SSL certificate generated; thumbprint: $thumbprint"

    # Create the hashtables of settings to be used.
    $valueset = @{
        Hostname = $SubjectName
        CertificateThumbprint = $thumbprint
    }

    $selectorset = @{
        Transport = "HTTPS"
        Address = "*"
    }

    Write-Verbose "Enabling SSL listener."
    New-WSManInstance -ResourceURI 'winrm/config/Listener' -SelectorSet $selectorset -ValueSet $valueset
    Write-Log "Enabled SSL listener."
}
Else
{
    Write-Verbose "SSL listener is already active."

    # Force a new SSL cert on Listener if the $ForceNewSSLCert
    If ($ForceNewSSLCert)
    {

        # We cannot use New-SelfSignedCertificate on 2012R2 and earlier
        $thumbprint = New-LegacySelfSignedCert -SubjectName $SubjectName -ValidDays $CertValidityDays
        Write-HostLog "Self-signed SSL certificate generated; thumbprint: $thumbprint"

        $valueset = @{
            CertificateThumbprint = $thumbprint
            Hostname = $SubjectName
        }

        # Delete the listener for SSL
        $selectorset = @{
            Address = "*"
            Transport = "HTTPS"
        }
        Remove-WSManInstance -ResourceURI 'winrm/config/Listener' -SelectorSet $selectorset

        # Add new Listener with new SSL cert
        New-WSManInstance -ResourceURI 'winrm/config/Listener' -SelectorSet $selectorset -ValueSet $valueset
    }
}

# Check for basic authentication.
$basicAuthSetting = Get-ChildItem WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Basic"}

If ($DisableBasicAuth) 
{
    If (($basicAuthSetting.Value) -eq $true) 
    {
        Write-Verbose "Disabling basic auth support."
        Set-Item -Path "WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\Basic" -Value $false
        Write-Log "Disabled basic auth support."
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Verbose "Basic auth is already disabled."
    }
} 
Else 
{
    If (($basicAuthSetting.Value) -eq $false)
    {
        Write-Verbose "Enabling basic auth support."
        Set-Item -Path "WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\Basic" -Value $true
        Write-Log "Enabled basic auth support."
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Verbose "Basic auth is already enabled."
    }
}

# If EnableCredSSP if set to true
If ($EnableCredSSP)
{
    # Check for CredSSP authentication
    $credsspAuthSetting = Get-ChildItem WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth | Where {$_.Name -eq "CredSSP"}
    If (($credsspAuthSetting.Value) -eq $false)
    {
        Write-Verbose "Enabling CredSSP auth support."
        Enable-WSManCredSSP -role server -Force
        Write-Log "Enabled CredSSP auth support."
    }
}

If ($GlobalHttpFirewallAccess) {
    Enable-GlobalHttpFirewallAccess
}

# Configure firewall to allow WinRM HTTPS connections.
$fwtest1 = netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="Allow WinRM HTTPS"
$fwtest2 = netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="Allow WinRM HTTPS" profile=any
If ($fwtest1.count -lt 5)
{
    Write-Verbose "Adding firewall rule to allow WinRM HTTPS."
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule profile=any name="Allow WinRM HTTPS" dir=in localport=5986 protocol=TCP action=allow
    Write-Log "Added firewall rule to allow WinRM HTTPS."
}
ElseIf (($fwtest1.count -ge 5) -and ($fwtest2.count -lt 5))
{
    Write-Verbose "Updating firewall rule to allow WinRM HTTPS for any profile."
    netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Allow WinRM HTTPS" new profile=any
    Write-Log "Updated firewall rule to allow WinRM HTTPS for any profile."
}
Else
{
    Write-Verbose "Firewall rule already exists to allow WinRM HTTPS."
}

# Test a remoting connection to localhost, which should work.
$httpResult = Invoke-Command -ComputerName "localhost" -ScriptBlock {$env:COMPUTERNAME} -ErrorVariable httpError -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$httpsOptions = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck

$httpsResult = New-PSSession -UseSSL -ComputerName "localhost" -SessionOption $httpsOptions -ErrorVariable httpsError -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

If ($httpResult -and $httpsResult)
{
    Write-Verbose "HTTP: Enabled | HTTPS: Enabled"
}
ElseIf ($httpsResult -and !$httpResult)
{
    Write-Verbose "HTTP: Disabled | HTTPS: Enabled"
}
ElseIf ($httpResult -and !$httpsResult)
{
    Write-Verbose "HTTP: Enabled | HTTPS: Disabled"
}
Else
{
    Write-Log "Unable to establish an HTTP or HTTPS remoting session."
    Throw "Unable to establish an HTTP or HTTPS remoting session."
}
Write-VerboseLog "PS Remoting has been successfully configured for Ansible."
```