# What is "principal" argument of kerbros-sspi?

Tags: python, kerberos, winrm

I was trying to connect to remote machine via WinRM in Python (pywinrm) using domain account, following the instruction in

[How to connect to remote machine via WinRM in Python (pywinrm) using domain account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324023/how-to-connect-to-remote-machine-via-winrm-in-python-pywinrm-using-domain-acco)

using

```
session = winrm.Session(server, auth=('user@DOMAIN', 'doesNotMatterBecauseYouAreUsingAKerbTicket'), transport='kerberos')
```

but I got this:

```
NotImplementedError("Can't use 'principal' argument with kerberos-sspi.")
```

I googled "principal argument" and I got its meaning in mathematics,which is in complex_analysis (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) and definitely not the right meaning. I'm not a native English speaker and I got stuck here.

The original code is here:
https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos/blob/master/requests_kerberos/kerberos_.py

```
def generate_request_header(self, response, host, is_preemptive=False):

"""

Generates the GSSAPI authentication token with kerberos.

If any GSSAPI step fails, raise KerberosExchangeError

with failure detail.

"""


        # Flags used by kerberos module.

        gssflags = kerberos.GSS_C_MUTUAL_FLAG | kerberos.GSS_C_SEQUENCE_FLAG

        if self.delegate:

            gssflags |= kerberos.GSS_C_DELEG_FLAG


        try:

            kerb_stage = "authGSSClientInit()"

            # contexts still need to be stored by host, but hostname_override

            # allows use of an arbitrary hostname for the kerberos exchange

            # (eg, in cases of aliased hosts, internal vs external, CNAMEs

            # w/ name-based HTTP hosting)

            kerb_host = self.hostname_override if self.hostname_override is not None else host

            kerb_spn = "{0}@{1}".format(self.service, kerb_host)

            

            kwargs = {}

            # kerberos-sspi: Never pass principal. Raise if user tries to specify one.

            if not self._using_kerberos_sspi:

                kwargs['principal'] = self.principal

            elif self.principal:

                raise NotImplementedError("Can't use 'principal' argument with kerberos-sspi.")
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why have you tried to type out the error messages yourself, given that they're in the code you also cut-and-pasted? And have you read [the documentation of the package you're using](https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos#explicit-principal)?

Comment: You definitely found the wrong link to what a principal means. Try this  http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5.4/doc/krb5-user/What-is-a-Kerberos-Principal_003f.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe 1.For highlights, as a habit when I speak Chinese. 2.Thanks for reminding, I did miss the sentence “Explicit Principal is currently not supported when using kerberos-sspi. Providing a value for principal in this scenario will raise NotImplementedError.” and I was using Windows Server 2012, for I can only read these document on mobile phone when working. But then how can I use kerberos in pywinrm to support domain users if providing a value for principal is not supported in Windows?

Comment: No, I mean rather than copying them; you've spelled several things wrong (see also the title).

Comment: @cricket_007 so simply saying, it is fairly equal to domain username in this case?

Comment: I don't know Kerberos too well, but in an sense, yes. I believe it's more involved than a simple username, though

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry and I edited it. How about my 2nd question in reply:"How can I use kerberos in pywinrm to support domain users if providing a value for principal is not supported in Windows?"